# cURL to Axios POST Request (Twilio) ERR status code 415

Tags: http, curl, request, axios, twilio

I'm trying to convert this cURL cmd request into it's Axios equivalent.

```
 curl -X POST "https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/${service_uid}/Assets/${asset_uid}/Versions" \
      -F Content=@./mapping/mapping.json; type=application/json \
      -F Path=mapping.json \
      -F Visibility=private \
      -u ACe88280704ee8ce71f1f9c969cf1b3583:0c9fa298a63f64fefe499c1acfc604c8
```

I've loaded the mapping as a JSON and the Axios request I've tried to make is

```
url = `https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/${service_uid}/Assets/${asset_uid}/Versions`

    var contentType = "application/json"
    var contentOpts = {
        filename: "mapping.json",
        contentType: contentType
    }

    form = new FormData();
    form.append('Path', "mapping.json");
    form.append('Visibility', "private");
    form.append('Content', JSON.stringify(mapping), contentOpts);


    await axios.post(url, form,  {
        headers: {
          username: client.accountSid,
          password: client.password
        }
      });
```

I received this error message

```
Request failed with status code 415
```

Comment: Your `url` definition looks a bit odd, have you tried without the `""`, so only with the backticks?

Comment: @yvesonline well spotted, fixed one issue now uncovered another one haha.